# jQuery not working right, possible conflicts with Prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype

I'm sorry for the vague title.

I'm making a new theme for my company's website, and I've got both jQuery tabs and a slider on the page.

Both the tabs and slider aren't working though - I'm not too sure why. I inherited the design and simply changed the theme - I'm thinking it might have something to do with multiple jQuery scripts being loaded - the slider throws an error that the method `.split()` doesn't exist, and the tabs just don't work the way they should.

Comment: Call `jQuery.noConflict` and then use `jQuery` instead of `$` consistently *before* you do any other work with JS.

Comment: Where does the noConflict call need to be placed? after jQuery main scripts but before jquery UI? or just after all of it?

Comment: Don't think that specific circumstance makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.plugin.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.moreplugin.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.noConflict.js</script></action>

<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

in page.xml layout.

jquery.noConflict.js file:

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
```

After that you can call jQuery() function everywhere you wish.
The order is: jquery -> jquery plugin -> jquery no conflict -> prototype

Comment: Figured out the problem, and you are right. I was loading jquery, then prototype, then the jquery plugins. I moved jQuery to after prototype and plugins were loaded, then noconflicted it, and now it works great! Thanks

Comment: you know, that's a good question. Yours was what fixed it. i'll re-accept it

Answer (score 2):

Explosion Pills is right -- you should use jQuery.noConflict.  Import jQuery first, then, before you import Prototype, insert the line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

If you do that, everywhere else in your app where you reference jQuery, do `jQuery(...)` or `jQuery.` instead of `$(...)` or `$.`.  It shouldn't mess up your script imports unless those scripts you're importing are written badly and don't define $ for themselves.

Comment: I've done this, but it's still not working correctly. Should I be importing every jquery library I'm using, and then do the noConflict, and then import prototype? Right now the order is jquery_min -> noConflict -> prototype -> jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the following snippets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($) {
    $.ajax(...);
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

, which won't conflict with Prototype and remain to use '$' for jQuery. 
Here's some more information: 
http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/using-jquery-in-magento-with-good-programming-practice.html